# Why does my array become empty when I pass it to Twig

Tags: php, html, twig, slim

Controller:

```
$app->get('/', function() use($app){
    $feeds[0] = "test";
    $feeds['name'] = "name";
    $app->render('home.twig', $feeds);
})->name('home');
```

Twig:

```
<h2>
{% if feeds %}
    {{ feeds[0] }}
    {{ feeds.name }}
{% else %}
    <h2 style="color: white">TEST</h2>
{% endif %}
</h2>
```

It displays TEST instead of the array that I used. When I try to var_dump it, the array contains the data yet it shows as empty in Twig.

Comment: Maybe you should pass an array instead. `$app->render('home.twig', array(‘feed’ => $feeds));`

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead:

```
$app->render('home.twig', array('feed' => $feeds));
```